# sql practice query issue

Tags: sql

Trying to solve some queries from [sql zoo](http://sqlzoo.net) to practice sql skills

I have a table `nobel` with columns `(year, subject, winner)` which have information on the people who have earned noble prizes in a given year for a given subject.

So I assume the primary key to be composite of `(year, subject, winner)`.

The problem I am trying to solve is: Show winners who have won more than one subject.

The output of the SQL query should have just one column with the winner names.

I feel that I should be using `group by` and using `having(count(winner)) >1`. But I think I need to group by by subject and that's where my problem is.

I am not looking for a query. If you can provide me with more logic than query that would help. Also do not worry about the database it needs to be implemented on. I am just practicing these questions.

Comment: Why downvote this? It's an excellent question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should give you people who won on multiple **different** subjects in any number of years:

```
SELECT winner
FROM nobel
GROUP BY winner
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT subject) > 1
```

For a specific year, just add `WHERE year = <whatever>` (or `GROUP BY year` for all years), though no person in history won a Nobel for two subjects in a single year - but who knows what future brings ;)

Comment: forgot the distinct operator!! Thanks

Comment: Why are some omitted? Try this: `select winner, subject, count(subject) from nobel group by winner having count(subject) > 1` and you'll see that there are many more (ex: International Committee of the Red Cross has won 3 for Peace). But it still shows only 2 records! I know that your solution passes sqlzoo test but is it actually the correct answer?

Comment: @ShripadKrishna Non-aggregated fields in your select list are not completely covered by GROUP BY.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic Thanks and yes you are absolutely right! I misunderstood the problem itself. The key point was "more than one subject" which I don't know how I skipped that.

Answer (score 1):

You should really consider creating a [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) or [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) database on your local machine so that you can practice making queries.

The primary key is irrelevant to your question, don't worry about it.

You are thinking along the correct lines - you will need a `group by` and `having` clause. If you group by winner, then your proposed query should work. I've added a count of wins.

```
select
  winner, count(winner) as wins
from
  nobel
group by winner
having (count(winner)) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT winner
FROM nobel 
GROUP BY winner 
HAVING COUNT(winner) > 1
```

This is the simplest way to do it ......

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work, since it doesn't check that the winner has one in multiple subjects, only that they've won multiple time.